# Usage of python-readability

Tags: python, readability

(https://github.com/buriy/python-readability)

I am struggling using this library and I can't find any documentation for it. (Is there any?)

There are some kind of useable pieces calling help(Document) but there is still something wrong.

My code so far:

```
from readability.readability import Document
import requests

url = 'http://www.somepage.com'

html = requests.get(url, verify=False).content
readable_article = Document(html,   negative_keywords='test_keyword').summary()

with open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as test_file:
    test_file.write(readable_article)
```

According to the help(Document) output, it should be possible to use a list for the input of the negative_keywords.

```
readable_article = Document(html, negative_keywords=['test_keyword1', 'test-keyword2').summary()
```

Gives me a bunch of errors I don't understand:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   163, in summary
>       candidates = self.score_paragraphs()   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   300, in score_paragraphs
>       candidates[parent_node] = self.score_node(parent_node)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   360, in score_node
>       content_score = self.class_weight(elem)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   348, in class_weight
>       if self.negative_keywords and self.negative_keywords.search(feature): AttributeError: 'list' object
>   has no attribute 'search' Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   163, in summary
>       candidates = self.score_paragraphs()   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   300, in score_paragraphs
>       candidates[parent_node] = self.score_node(parent_node)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   360, in score_node
>       content_score = self.class_weight(elem)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line
>   348, in class_weight
>       if self.negative_keywords and self.negative_keywords.search(feature): AttributeError: 'list' object
>   has no attribute 'search'

Could some one give me please a hint on the error or how to deal with it?

Comment: That's not a bunch of errors, but the error stack.  It is showing one error, and all the function calls that led to that point.  In other words information on how it got to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the library code. If you look at [`compile_pattern`](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability/blob/master/readability/readability.py#L67):

```
def compile_pattern(elements):
    if not elements:
        return None
    elif isinstance(elements, (list, tuple)):
        return list(elements)
    elif isinstance(elements, regexp_type):
        return elements
    else:
        # assume string or string like object
        elements = elements.split(',')
        return re.compile(u'|'.join([re.escape(x.lower()) for x in elements]), re.U)
```

You can see that it only returns a regex if the `elements` is not None, not a list or tuple, and not a regular expression.

Later on, though, it assumes that `self.negative_keywords` is a regular expression. So, I suggest you input your list as a string in the form of `"test_keyword1,test_keyword2"`. This will make sure that `compile_pattern` returns a regular expression which should fix the error.

Comment: @user3199535 Of course! There's already a [pull request](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability/pull/74) that someone made to fix this issue.